# Does scatter list pointer passed to sg_init_table() function need to be allocated before?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma, pci

In a linux kernel PCI driver module.
We have a function to initialize dma scatter list:
`sg_init_table(struct scatterlist *sg, unsigned int nents);`

For the scatterlist pointor `sg`, should we allocate some memory for it, like using `kcalloc`;
or we just declare it like: `struct scatterlist * sg` and then pass it to `sg_init_table`?

Thx for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no value to the caller in passing an uninitialized or invalid pointer value of any type to any function, other than simply to pad out the function's argument list with an argument of the expected type.  The caller conveys no valid information to the function that way, and it provides no mechanism for the function to return any information.  In particular, it does not provide a mechanism by which the called function can allocate memory on behalf of the caller.  Pointers, like any other argument, are passed *by value*, so when a function modifies one of its parameters, that is not visible to the caller.

The function signature you present makes sense only for initializing an *existing* object of type `struct scatterlist`, or an array of such objects, or allocated memory intended to hold such an object or array.  If that struct needs to be dynamically allocated then yes, the caller must perform the allocation and pass a pointer to the result.

Under some circumstances, however, it might be suitable for the caller to declare a local `struct` object, and to pass its address, something like this:

```
struct scatterlist sl;

sg_init_table(&sl, DEFAULT_NENTS);
```

or maybe

```
struct scatterlist sl[DEFAULT_NENTS];

sg_init_table(sl, DEFAULT_NENTS);
```

, depending on details of how `sg_init_table()` is meant to behave.

Similarly, it might be suitable to pass the address of a *global* struct.  Do be aware of the lifetime of local objects -- unless declared `static`, local objects do not survive the end of the function call in which they were declared.

Comment: Shouldn't your local storage be declared as `struct scatterlist sl[DEFAULT_NENTS];`?

Comment: @IanAbbott, perhaps, but not necessarily; the role of the function's second parameter is unclear.  Relative to what I had *meant* to write, I dropped an `&` operator (now fixed), but your variation might match the function implementation better.  I added it as an alternative.

Comment: The implementation is easy enough to see. It is in lib/scatterlist.c in the kernel sources. Your `struct scatterlist sl; sg_init_table(&sl, DEFAULT_NENTS);` will trash kernel memory if `DEFAULT_NENTS` is greater than 1. And a scatterlist with a single entry is not much use, as you might as well do a single transfer (not a scatter-gather transfer) in that case.